# Wallet app not sending registration request to my web server

Tags: ios, swift, wallet

I am developing a mobile ticket app where I have created a pass , I am displaying the pass using PKAddPassesViewController pass is displayed without any problem and its also added successfully to wallet application , the problem is that when the pass is added to the wallet it is not sending any registration request to my backend api as mentioned in the docs . I am running node.js server locally on http so I have also enabled HTTP for passkit testing in developer settings but still there is no request on the server.

some fields in pass.json are

```
  "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.com.commonapp.projectpocket",
    "serialNumber": "E5982H-I2",
    "teamIdentifier": "U72SPX5AGJ",
    "webServiceURL": "http://localhost:1337",
```

Looking if someone faced same issues

Comment: Sorry everyone I was using wrong pass which was pointing to wrong api i changed the end point and now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Sorry by mistake I was using wrong pass which was pointing to wrong api and now i updated the pass and its working fine